# Tricky Menu (HTML + CSS) for a WordPress template

Tags: html, css, wordpress

[image]

So we have the menu above. That I need to construct for a WordPress template. I have no idea how to make the hover and active states. Untill now I have this:

HTML (*followed how WordPress will generate the code*):

```
<nav id="nav-main" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-primary-navigation-container">
        <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Menu Link
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Menu Link
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Menu Link
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Menu Link
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" title="">
                    Menu Link
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- #menu-primary-navigation -->
    </div><!-- .menu-primary-navigation-container -->
</nav><!-- #access -->
```

Then I have the CSS:

```
#nav-main {
    width: 956px;
    height: 44px;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    background: url(images/bg-nav-main.jpg) repeat-x;
}
    .menu-primary-navigation-container {}
        #menu-primary-navigation {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
            #menu-primary-navigation li {
                height: 44px;
                display: inline-block;
            }
                #menu-primary-navigation li a {
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    line-height: 44px;
                    padding: 0 46px;
                }
                    #menu-primary-navigation li a:hover {}
```

And this is all. Here I am stucked. Those slashes are the bad points of this menu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make graphics that way:

[image: yellow represents transparent color]

Yellow represents transparent color. 
Then add negative margin to `<li>` so they will be next to each other without spaces.

Comment: Isn't it just matter of good cut? Give that menu element curved edges with smooth opacity, so two elements next to each other will give you that gradient slashlines.

Comment: I would like to show you prepared example, but I'm afraid that my "artistic" skills are quite poor.

Answer (score 1):

To make the active state you have to add some php to the menu to check the current site:

```
<nav id="nav-main" role="navigation">
<div class="menu-primary-navigation-container">
    <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
        <li  <?php if (is_page('home')) { echo "class='active'"; }?> >
            <a href="#" title="">
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li  <?php if (is_page('menulink')) { echo "class='active'"; }?> >
            <a href="#" title="">
                Menu Link
            </a>
        </li>
```

For more information read this tutorial here: [Tutorial](http://www.designisphilosophy.com/css/highlight-current-page-in-wordpress-menus/)

Then you have to make rectangular images for each menubutton and define it for the `<li>` elements as a background. You can also make one for all menu elements. With the 'active' class, which get set up by wordpress, you can define a different background for the active menu element.

For the hover of the menu elements you just have to add a background definition in css for 
`#menu-primary-navigation li a:hover {}`